# Blu-Ray on Windows 7 HTPC

Tags: windows-7, blu-ray, htpc

I have configured an HTPC with the following components:

- Motherboard: Intel DG45ID
- CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad 8300
- Graphics: Integrated Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X4500HD (using HDMI)
- RAM: 8 GB OCZ
- OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
- Monitor: Emprex 32-inch LCD (HDCP compliant)

So far, I have had 2 failed attempts at finding a Blu-Ray drive which will work on this machine. I have tried an LG CH08LS10 and a Lite-On IHES108. These drives work with CDs and DVDs, but are never able to recognize a Blu-Ray disc.

With the LG, I upgraded firmware to 2.00 and installed Cyberlink PowerDVD 9. The Lite-On doesn't appear to have any additional drivers or firmware that I can find.

Is there something wrong with my setup, or am I just not finding the right Blu-Ray drives?

One more thing to note, the Cyberlink Blu-Ray Advisor tells me that my Operating System and Graphics Card Driver are not able to play Blu-Ray discs. I have the latest drivers for my motherboard/graphics installed, and I have heard of others using Windows 7 for Blu-Ray playback, so I don't know where the issue is here.

UPDATE: Sorry I haven't visited this question lately. I'm dealing with some [motherboard issues](https://superuser.com/questions/81215/computer-will-not-boot-to-bios). I will get back to this as soon as I'm able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my motherboard was bad -- it died a few days after this post (see link in post above). I replaced the motherboard, updated the BIOS to the 12-24-2009 firmware, and now have Blu-Ray playback!

Comment: First Blu-ray watched -- Star Trek, of course

Answer (score 3):

For Blu-Ray, as far as the drive itself, you really just need one that will actually READ the discs.  The UDF file system is built into Vista/7.

I use a LG burner, and it reads discs regardless if software is installed.  If you go to "My Computer" can you actually EXPLORE a blu-ray disc?  If so, your drive is fine.  If not, the drive, cable, or SATA controller has an issue.

Now, you did not mention what video card and monitor you have.  Blu-Ray usually requires HDCP (High Definition Content Protection) encryption for DVI and HDMI on the video card AND the monitor (just because a video card/monitor has DVI does not mean it has HDCP).  Some software packages will allow you to use VGA, but not all of them.

Just in case your issue is the DRM mess that is Blu-Ray, you can try a version of Slysoft AnyDVD HD from slysoft.com.  That basically bypasses all Blu-Ray, DVD, and HD-DVD DRM on the fly.

I use Windows7 for Blu-Ray...so there's someone else out there.

Comment: If you don't have HDCP, AnyDVD HD will remove that requirement, too.

Comment: I cannot explorer Blu-Ray discs. I can hear the disk drive trying to spin up and recognize the disc, but it never speeds up and shows me anything. See post edit for video card/monitor info.

Comment: Well, if you can't even Explore a Blu-Ray, I think you may have a problem with the drive, the SATA cable, or drive controller.

I would start by grabbing the most recent CHIPSET (Intel) and GPU (Intel chipset) drivers from Intel rather than the auto-installed ones.

Also, are you using HDMI?