# Computer will not boot to BIOS

Tags: boot, bios, htpc

I have a custom-built HTPC with the following specs:

```
* Motherboard: Intel DG45ID
* CPU: Intel Core 2 Quad 8300
* Graphics: Integrated Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X4500HD (using HDMI)
* RAM: 8 GB OCZ
* OS: Windows 7 Home Premium 64-bit
```

It was working smoothly up until yesterday, when it froze during Hulu playback and I had to hard reboot. I have not been able to get it to boot back up, and it won't even load the BIOS screen or do the single beep when the computer turns on.

All of the fans are spinning, and I have tried removing all connections except for CPU, CPU fan, motherboard main power, and one stick of RAM.

I have tried switching out the RAM. I have also tried switching out the HDMI monitor for a DVI monitor.

UPDATE: When I switch on power supply, components (CPU, CPU fan, motherboard) power on for about 4 seconds before shutting down briefly and powering back on.

UPDATE2: Tried a cheap power supply from Frys and witnessed same behavior. Am in the RMA process with NewEgg at the moment for the motherboard. Will update again when I receive and test with the new one.

UPDATE3: Returned the faulty motherboard and the computer is now working again.

Comment: no video... try an external video card or reset the bios. if you don't know how. you will have to open your computer check the MB and look for a battery a cr2032 or of the like. close to that you should see a jumper or button that will allow you to reset the bios.. if all that fails remove the battery and unplug the box .. replug it in and try it then.

Comment: Tried resetting the MB as per the instructions (remove jumper for 30sec). Also tried removing the battery for 30sec. No change in behavior.

Comment: I will be going to Frys to grab a spare PS to test with. Will let you all know how it goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's time to start swapping components.  I'd start with the power supply first.  No need to take the old on all the way out of the case, just take a known-working PSU and plug it into the motherboard.  Start with the power supply, then try the video card, then the motherboard.

Once you find the faulty component, replace it and through your known-working spare back in a safe place.

Answer (score 6):

If you remove all RAM sticks from the motherboard,
and the boot up attempt then does not indicate memory-problem with beeps,
it is very likely that you have problems with the motherboard power regulation components.

For example, take a look at the capacitors on the mother board near the power-supply cable connector -- do they all look fine? are any of them discolored, out-of-shape or 'leaking'?

---

If you do not get memory-missing/failed beeps when you boot with no memory,
it is very likely that the POST (power on self test) of the motherboard never started.

If there are not problems on the board, you need to look at the power supply itself. Maybe the lower voltage power rails for the processor etc have malfunctioned. This would let the fans work but will not power the CPU (for example).

Comment: Took all RAM out, no beeps. No capacitors discolored or otherwise.

Comment: Man, does it feel stupid to find out after freaking out over the health of the motherboard that the problem was a loose power cable to the processor!

Answer (score 0):

As Russ suggested you should start swapping components, especially the power supply and the CPU. This sounds like either the motherboard or the CPU is gone.